# Delayed page load of external resource in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that loads a document from an external API. I understand that on the first load there will be a delay in displaying the contents.

I am caching the document with `shareReplay()` for future page visits and there is still a delay. The document was originally loaded in `ngOnInit()`, so I moved it to the constructor and there is still a delay. I understand the nature of the problem, but don't know how to prevent the delay it for future visits.

Component:

```
@Component({
   selector: "document",
   template: "<div [innerHTML]='body$ | async'></div>"
})
export class DocumentComponent {
   constructor(private readonly documents: DocumentsService) {
      this.body$ = this.documents.get("demo.md");
   }
   public body$!: Observable<string>;
}
```

Service:

```
--- omitted for brevity ---

   public get(document: string): Observable<string> {
      return this.http
         .get(`${url}/api/documents/${document}`, { responseType: "text" })
         .pipe(shareReplay(1)));
   }

--- omitted for brevity ---
```

Note that although "demo.md" is being requested, the response is formatted as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

ApiCacheInterceptor that can cache HTTP responses from certain API endpoints. The interceptor uses the HttpInterceptor class and its intercept() method to handle all HTTP requests and responses.

When a request is intercepted, the interceptor checks if the request endpoint is in a predefined set of endpoints to cache. If the endpoint is in the set, the interceptor checks if the response is already cached. If the response is cached, the interceptor returns the cached response. If the response is not cached, the interceptor sends the request to the server, caches the response, and returns the response to the original caller.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const endpoitObj = {
  API: {
    Document: {
      Get: 'get document api',
    },
  },
};

@Injectable()
export class ApiCacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  //cache to store response data
  private _cache = new Map<string, HttpResponse<any>>();

  private endpointsToCache = new Set([endpoitObj.API.Document.Get]);

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //Remove the API base url from the request url
    const url = request.url.replace(environment.apiUrl, '');

    //check if the request endpoint is in the set of endpoints to cache
    if (this.endpointsToCache.has(url)) {
      //Retrieve the cached response
      const cachedResponse = this._cache.get(request.url);

      //If the response is found in the cache, return it a a observabke of HttpResponse
      if (cachedResponse) {
        return of(cachedResponse);
      }

      //if the response is not found in the cache send the request and cache the response
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap((response) => {
          if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this._cache.set(request.url, response);
          }
        })
      );
    }

    //if the request endpoint is not in the set of endpoints to cache
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll follow this pattern and I'm going to experiment using local storage or IndexedDB as a backing store to survive browser refreshes. Thanks!